# How can I center a fragment?

Tags: android

I have a fragment THAT IS RIGHT JYSTFIED NOW, IS THEFRE A WAY TO CENTER IT?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tedpo.bitcoinproject2.MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.tedpo.bitcoinproject2.BlankFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Add Excahnge"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post the complete xml please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `layout_gravity="center"` which tells Android how to align the view relative to the parent.

If you want, in your parent view, you can use `gravity="center"` which tells the view how to layout its content.